# How to redirect the browser after a json post with go and javascript?

Tags: javascript, go

We are trying to send an HTML form in JSON to a GO code. We already achieve that, but, now we're confused because we can't make the browser to redirect to corresponding webpage. The redirect instruction works fine sending the json directly on Insomnia (it returns the success state and displays the new page), but not in the browser. Perhaps we're missing some code, but we can't find what are we missing. Please, help.

The javascript code that sends the json:

```
  jQuery(document).on('submit', '#login', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/login/',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify($(this).serializeFormJSON())
        })
        .done(function(response){
            location.href = 'response';
        })
        .fail(function(resp){
            console.log("resp");
        })
        .always(function(){
            console.log("complete");
        })
    });
```

The Go code that validates this form:

```
    func POSTLoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var user users.User
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        } else {
            validCredentials, err := users.ValidarCredenciales(user)
            if err != nil {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
            } else if validCredentials {
                err = cookies.GenerarCookie(w, r, user.Email)
                if err != nil {
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
                } else {
                    http.Redirect(w, r, "/dashboard/", http.StatusSeeOther)
                }
            } else {
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/forbidden/", http.StatusSeeOther)
            }
        }
    }


    func GetDashboardUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        exists, err := cookies.VerifyCookie(r)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        } else if exists {
            http.ServeFile(w, r, "static/template.html")
        } else {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you issue an AJAX request, that's all JavaScript, not the page the user sees. So when your AJAX request gets a redirect response, it's the AJAX request that gets redirected. The page the user sees will only redirected if the URL they navigate to returns a redirect. If you want a JavaScript to change the browser page, you'll have to write the JS so that it does that, it won't happen automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Adrian. The problem is that the response I get from the go code is an HTML (this I know it because I tried printing the data on the console logs of javascript). I mean, I know I can use, for example, "location.href" to change the url, but i don't get any url.

Comment: Right - the redirect is already done when you get the response in your script, that's how redirects are supposed to work. If you want to redirect the browser to some URL based on the response you get from your AJAX request, you'll need to actually return the URL in the reponse instead of trying to redirect the AJAX request itself.